# Using Dynamic Variables/Placeholders in Yaml File

Tags: python, bash, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I have a Google AppEngine Yaml File like so:

```
entrypoint: mlflow server \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --workers 4 \
    --backend-store-uri postgresql+psycopg2://$DB_USER:$DB_PASS@/$DB_NAME?host=/cloudsql/<project_id>:us-east1:<cloud-sql-instance> \
    --default-artifact-root gs://$GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET \
    --port $PORT
service: mlflow-tracking-server
runtime: python37
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <project_id>:us-east1:<cloud-sql-instance>
resources:
    cpu: 4
    memory_gb: 12
    disk_size_gb: 60
```

How can I replace these placeholder variables with their respective values?

I know for Kubernetes, I have a bash script that does this.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed "s/GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY_ENC_REPLACE/$(printf "%s" "$GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY_ENC"|base64)/g" mlflow_gcp_secret.yaml | \
sed "s/GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET_REPLACE/$(printf "%s" "$GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET"|base64)/g" | \
sed "s/CLOUDSQL_USER_REPLACE/$(printf "%s" "$DB_USER"|base64)/g" | \
sed "s/CLOUDSQL_PASS_REPLACE/$(printf "%s" "$DB_PASS"|base64)/g" | \
sed "s/CLOUDSQL_DB_REPLACE/$(printf "%s" "$DB_NAME"|base64)/g" | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

Now I want to do something for an App Engine yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `sed` example should be enough for you to make progress on this task. However, here's a second approach.  Since all of your place holders look like environment variables, you can use bash interpolation to make the substitutions for you.

Consider this code:

```
DBUSER=user
DBPASS=pass
GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET=bucket

cat  > 4appengine <<EOF
entrypoint: mlflow server \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --workers 4 \
    --backend-store-uri postgresql+psycopg2://$DB_USER:$DB_PASS@/$DB_NAME?host=/cloudsql/<project_id>:us-east1:<cloud-sql-instance> \
    --default-artifact-root gs://$GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET \
    --port $PORT
service: mlflow-tracking-server
runtime: python37
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <project_id>:us-east1:<cloud-sql-instance>
resources:
    cpu: 4
    memory_gb: 12
    disk_size_gb: 60
EOF
```

Above, the script with variables replaced will be written to the file: 4appengine.

Comment: When copying and pasting, please make sure there are no extra spaces after the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool dedicated for that:

```
envsubst '$DB_USER:$DB_PASS:$GCP_STORAGE_BUCKET' <cfg.yml
```

will replace all the variables listed with the ones in the environment

demo: https://ideone.com/6mEQk9

Note: envsubst is part of gnu gettext, it's pretty common, but it may not be available by default.